# How to solve $(y^2+u)u_x+yu_y=0$ by the condition:

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

How can I solve the PDE:

$(y^2+u)u_x+yu_y=0$ by the condition:

$u=0$ is on $x=0.5y^2$, in the area of $y>0$.

How many solutions are there?

So I tried to solve $x(t)=0.5s^2 +se^t-s$

But I can see only the trivial solution $u=0$, other than that is it means there are infinite solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(y^2+u)u_x+yu_y=0$$
Using method of characteristics:
$$\frac {dx}{(y^2+u)}=\frac {dy}{y}=\frac {du}{0}$$
$$du=0 \implies u=c_1$$
From the second equation we have:
$$\frac {dx}{(y^2+u)}=y\frac {dy}{y^2}$$
Substracting fractions we have:
$$\frac {dx-ydy}{c_1}=\frac {dy}{y}$$
$$\frac {d(x-\frac 12y^2)}{c_1}=\frac {dy}{y}$$
Integrating:
$$x-\frac 12y^2=c_1\ln ({y})+c_2$$
$$c_2=x-\frac 12y^2-c_1\ln ({y})$$
$$\boxed{f(c_2)=c_1 \implies u(x,y)=f(x-\frac 12y^2-u\ln ({y}))}$$
From the given condition we have:
$$u=0 \implies u(\frac {y^2}2,y)=0 $$
$$u(x,y)=f(x-\frac 12y^2-u\ln ({y}))$$
$$0=f(\frac 12y^2-\frac 12y^2-0\ln ({y})) \implies f(0)=0$$
Finally,
$$\boxed{f(0)=0  \text { and } u(x,y)=f(x-\frac 12y^2-u\ln ({y})) }$$

Comment: So it means the trivial solution and infinite solutions right?

Comment: Yes @Deb.U the intitial condition allows lots of functions that fullfil the condition $f(0)=0$

Comment: Can u elaborate about the step of subtracting fractions? Didn't follow the result there

Comment: Oh it's very simple if you have $\frac a b=\frac cd $ then you can substract numerator and denominator and equate that to one of the original fraction. Like $\frac {a-c}{b-d}=\frac a b$ I used that tricks because i have a fraction with $y^2$ at the denominator and another one with $y$ at the denominator so i multiplied the last one by y and susbsracted both fractions to get rid of the $y^2$ term @Deb.U

Comment: Got it, cool trick. Thanks

Comment: That's great that you have understood it. You can use this trick with differential equations whenever it's possible to do so. It makes things more simple sometimes. @Deb.U

Answer (score 0):

$$(y^2+u)u_x+yu_y=0$$
The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{y^2+u}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic equation commes from $du=0$ :
$$u=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{c_1^2+u}=\frac{dy}{y}$ which solution is $\frac{y^2}{2}+c_1\ln|y|=x+c_2$
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+u\ln|y|-x=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+u\ln|y|-x=F(u)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function to be determined according to the specified condition $u=0$ on $x=\frac{y^2}{2}$

$$\frac{y^2}{2}+0\ln|y|-\frac{y^2}{2}=F(0)\quad\implies\quad F(0)=0$$

They are an infinity of function $F(x)$ such as $F(0)=0$. Thus they are an infinity of solutions which satisfy the PDE and the specified condition.

For example in case of the function $F(X)=0$ 
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+u\ln|y|-x=0\quad\implies\quad u=\frac{x-\frac{y^2}{2}}{\ln|y|}$$

Other example, with the function $F(X)=c\:X$ that we put into the general solution where $X=u$.
$$\frac{y^2}{2}+u\ln|y|-x=c\,u\quad\implies\quad u=\frac{x-\frac{y^2}{2}}{\ln|y|-c}$$
And so on. One can take many other functions $F(X)$ insofar $F(0)=0$. All provide solution on the form of implicit equation. But all solutions cannot be expressed on explicit form.

This case of infinite number of solution is well-known when the specified condition coincides with a characteristic equation which is the present case (on the second characteristic curve).

Comment: Thank you, I'll read it In more depth.